# ASP.NET MVC RedirectToAction does not refresh the page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have controller action Refresh which just updates the current page. 
But when i call that action through RedirectoAction method, i got the problem, page has not updated. I must after that pres refresh button to call independently Refresh action, to got desired result.

This is my client side code. Which call my ResetItems action which in turn redirects to Refresh action.

```
function ResetSelectedItems() {

var guidId = $("#guidId")[0].value;
console.log(guidId[0].value);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/UploadFile/ResetItems',
    data: { guidId : guidId},

     }
)
```

}

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("ResetItems")]
    public ActionResult ResetItems(string guidId) 
    {
      //Some logic here updating in db etc..
      return RedirectToAction("Refresh");
    }

    [ActionName("Refresh")]
    public ActionResult Refresh(int? id) 
    {
      //Refresh logic which eventually render refresh the current view 
    }
```

Also i would like to mention that in this  project we  used IUnitOfWork pattern could it lead somehow this kind of  unexpected result?

P.S i am newbie in ASP.NET please do not judge tough

Edit: What i have done so far to find out what is going on.

I check through fiddler  whether i got cached result from browser or and i guess there is no  cache problem with browser because i got as a result http 200.

I used this attribute in both actions `[OutputCache(Location=System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.None)]`
 
Does not help.

Comment: using ajax you can not redirect `RedirectToAction("Refresh");` for that you can use `location.href` or you can use `return JavaScript("document.location.replace('" + Url.Action("Refresh", "Refresh") + "');");`

Comment: I am not redirecting directly from ajax call . i made a ajax call to my resetitem action after that i made redirectoaction to refreshaction

Comment: your `RedirectToAction("Refresh");` actually return your actions to your ajax success  you can get that in text in your `success` response of your ajax call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using AJAX request and it means that regardless of the response the html page will not be reloaded. 
I guess you need something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("ResetItems")]
public ActionResult ResetItems(string guidId) 
{
     //Some logic here updating in db etc..
     //string redirectUrl = Url.Action("Refresh", new { id = "your int id" });
     string redirectUrl = Url.Action("Refresh");
     return Json(new { redirectUrl });
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/UploadFile/ResetItems',
    data: { guidId : guidId},
    success: function (response) {
        window.location.replace(response.redirectUrl);
    }
});
```